# Concrete5.7: Expose "Design" toolbar for anon?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, concrete5

OK, I have an issue i was hoping someone could help me resolve.. i'm needing some special case functionality on a concrete5 site(5.7). As it stands you need to be logged-in to view the ccm-toolbar (the toolbar used for editing and adding blocks).

Now, the idea is to create a single-page (or sub-site) for the simple purpose of allowing 'visitors' to temporarily edit the design of the page... Much like a working demo, users should (while NOT logged in) be able to make changes in the "Design" side-panel.

My problem is i don't currently understand the new structure of 5.7  (namespaces, MVC's, routes) enough to simply "Dive in" and there is not much documentation when dealing 5.7 in general, and even less on customizing core functionality.

So i'm asking if anyone can point me to the right direction when it comes to setting up a page (or package) that allows me to expose a limited version of the toolbar for guest access. Should i use tools/routes, Page Controllers or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.7 doesn't exactly have a "tools" structure, we have routes that go to endpoints. While it is *possible* to do something like this, it's going to be very very difficult to get it working.

5.7 has a new construct of "panels" in the edit interface, in these panels we have - to the left - content and design changes specific to the page. Each of these changes are versioned and permissioned so an account is really necessary to keep everything in order.

That said, I think you could easily achieve this by logging people in to a demo account that only has permission to edit that one page but no permission to publish. Additionally, you can have a job that cleans out page versions that are older than a few hours to make sure it doesn't bloat.

Answer (score 1):

Im going to start off with something that you probably don't want to hear, you should never expose editing controls to the public.

The Design panel makes changes to the database (and can even impact all pages on the site)

What I would suggest is either making a "demo" site with a separate DB that users can login to, or, I would duplicate the functionality and have it save the settings in the session or cookies instead of the database.

If I were duplicating the design panel, I would build a package that would add several routes (similar to those of the design panel) and route controllers that would be duplicated from the core, I would then edit those controllers to not interact with the DB (as stated above).

I am not totally sure what you are trying to accomplish so it is hard for me to give a good response to this.

Mike

Comment: It's going to be a lot of work to recreate the panels on the front end especially the design panel. This is a great answer though.